# Selendroid, command android no longer available

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, selendroid

I'm starting with Selendroid. I followed the user guide, which is in the official site and I've had troubles after this command:

`java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk`

I obtain this error:

```
GRAVE: Error building server: io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.ShellCommandException: Error executing shell command: /home/ceibal/Android/Sdk/tools/android list avds
```

If I try executing this command line directly from terminal, I get the following message:

```
The android command is no longer available. For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

Then I tried:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager list avds
```

And the result was:

```
Warning: File /home/ceibal/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. Warning: Failed to find package list
```

Finally, if I check that the application(s) and the devices are recognized by opening a browser and navigating to:

http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status.

I can't connect to the server.

I wait for your help. Thanks in advance.